# wcf service returns Array instead of Observable Collection after Update

Tags: silverlight, wcf

Not sure why, but after updating my service reference the methods has started returning Array instead of Observable collection, previously it was returning Observable collection correctly.

i have tried configuring the service Reference but not luck.
i have tried SLSvcutil.exe also but not luck.

Please let me know why my silverlight app is behaving like this suddenly.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `Array` is the default setting for the collections on service client side. You can change the type that will be used for collections the following way.

From the Visual studio Right Click on your service reference, and select *"Configure Service Reference..."*. In the opened dialog select the required collection type: `System.Collection.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`.

If you want to use SLsvcUtil the /collectionType: option defines the type of collections.